# create method adding 2 values and assigning to to an attribute in rails table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the previous balance of a row and add it to a variable then add that to a params input value and assign it to a specific column attribute. If I rake db:migrate and the table is empty it will say acctbal is nil and bomb out. How do I get that attribute to be 0 for only the first time that current_user has deposited funds, such that following deposit can build off of it. As seen in the code below, second the "+" when adding the 2 values gives me an undefined nil error I just want to concatenate both values, how can I achieve this?

```
def create
 #@account = Account.new(account_params)
 # @account.save
 # respond_with(@account)

  @previous_balance = Account.where('user_id = ?', 
    current_user.id).order(:created_at).last.acctbal
  @account = Account.new(account_params)
  @account.email = current_user.email
  @account.user_id = current_user.id
  @account.acctbal = account_params[:deposit] + @previous_balance
  respond_to do |format|
     if @account.save
       format.html { redirect_to accounts_url, notice: 'Thank you and 
        enjoy.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @account }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: 
    :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
   end
```

My form partial:

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
 <% if @account.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@account.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this 
  account from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @account.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <% end %>




<div class="field">
<%= f.label :credit, "Deposit Amount" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :credit, size: 40 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :depotype, "Select Deposit Method" %><br>
<%= f.select :depotype, Account::DEPOSIT_TYPES, prompt: 'Select a deposit 
 method' %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit 'Deposit Funds' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Params method in controller:

```
  def account_params
   # params[:account]
  params.require(:account).permit(:created_at, :email, :credit, :debit, 
  :acctbal, :depotype)
   end
   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a `previous_balance` method to the `Account` model:

```
# models/account.rb
def self.previous_balance_for_user(user)
  where(user_id: user.id).order(:created_at).pluck(:acctbal).first || 0.0
end
```

Note that [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) just returns the values of `acctbal` (or `nil`).

With that method your controller can be changed to:

```
previous_balance = Account.previous_balance_for_user(current_user)
@account = Account.new(account_params.merge(
  user_id: current_user.id,
  email: current_user.email,
  acctbal: previous_balance + account_params[:credit].to_f
))
```

Comment: i see, when i do that i still have the "+" error can i make another method in the model that will take in 2 parameters and add them together and return the result so i can assign it in the controller?

Comment: if i implement this it errors out saying :                                                      no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array and has the "acctbal:" line highlighted

Comment: that params[:deposit] is data pulled from a create page that inputs a float value, i posted my _form.html.erb file

Comment: mayb it should be credit? i posted params method in controller

Comment: its saying now, no implicit conversion of Float into Array

Comment: i see, i will check that, i would love for this thing to work been at it since 3pm yesterday trying different ways to do this without success. i appreciate your help by the way

Comment: i entered a second deposit and account balance remained at 0

Comment: for the first insertion i entered 34.00 accountbal should be 34.00 and then so on using the previous bal to merge right?

Comment: ah thats what it was. now i have to see about a debit part of it, when the user is checking out from a cart it will deduct from this how can i put this in an if else method in the create action method in controller, i know this is really ugly and that i should make 2 methods in the controller that handle this, and i tried but after 23 hours of troubleshooting and getting nowhere and this was the farthest i got, i want to just do it in here.

Comment: its says i have to have 15 reputation. im new to stack i think that has something to do with it